# DML currently not allowed in Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am attempting to update information in a visualforce component, and am getting the error

> System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed

Everything I've searched says that that happens when you try to put an update in the constructor, but I don't think I'm doing that. Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Code is as follows:

**VisualForce Page:**

```
<apex:component>
   <apex:attribute name="MVRController" type="BC2MVR" description="The page's controller" />

          <!-- APPLY INFORMATION -->
         <apex:actionFunction reRender="serializedCapturedByHTML" name='callApplyMVR' action='{!MVRController.applyInformation}'>
              <apex:param name='violationsJSON' value='' assignTo="{!MVRController.violationsJSON}"></apex:param>
              <apex:param name='medicalInfoJSON' value='' assignTo="{!MVRController.medicalInfoJSON}"></apex:param>
         </apex:actionFunction>
         <script>
                     function MVRApply(){
                         let violationArr = [];
                         let medicalArr = [];
                         $('.violation-parent-div').each(function(){
                             let violation = {
                                 Id: $(this).attr('id'),
                                 Fine_Amount__c: $(this).find('.fine-amount').val(),
                                 Fine_State__c: $(this).find('.fine-state').val(),
                                 State_Points__c: $(this).find('.state-points').val()
                             }
                             violationArr.push(violation);
                         });
                         $('.medical-parent-div').each(function(){
                             let medInfo = {
                                 Id: $(this).attr('id'),
                                 Examiner_Name__c: $(this).find('.examiner-name').val(),
                                 Examiner_Phone__c: $(this).find('.examiner-phone').val(),
                                 Examiner_Registration_Number__c: $(this).find('.examiner-registration-num').val(),
                                 Examiner_Specialty_Code__c: $(this).find('.examiner-specialty-code').val()
                             }
                             medicalArr.push(medInfo);
                         });
                         let JSONViolations = JSON.stringify(violationArr);
                         let JSONMedInfo = JSON.stringify(medicalArr);
                         callApplyMVR(JSONViolations, JSONMedInfo);
                     }
           </script>
 </apex:component>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public void applyInformation(){
    Datetime now = Datetime.now();
    Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
    Datetime local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);

    tempNewViolation = (List<Violation__c>) JSON.deserialize(violationsJSON, List<Violation__c>.class);
    tempMedicalInfo = (List<Medical_Info__c>) JSON.deserialize(medicalInfoJSON, List<Medical_Info__c>.class);


    for(Violation__c newViolation : tempNewViolation){
        for(Violation__c oldViolation : violations){
            if(newViolation.Id == oldViolation.Id){
                System.debug('Found a match!');
                Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Violation__c.fields.getMap();
                for(String field : M.keySet()){
                    if((newViolation.get(field) != oldViolation.get(field)) && newViolation.get(field) != null){
                        if(oldViolation.Original_Object__c != null){
                            oldViolation.Original_Object__c = JSON.serialize(oldViolation);
                        }
                        oldViolation.put(field, newViolation.get(field));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(Medical_Info__c newMedInfo : tempMedicalInfo){
        for(Medical_Info__c oldMedInfo : medicalInfo){
            if(newMedInfo.Id == oldMedInfo.Id){
                Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Medical_Info__c.fields.getMap();
                for(String field : M.keySet()){
                    if((newMedInfo.get(field) != oldMedInfo.get(field)) && newMedInfo.get(field) != null){
                        if(oldMedInfo.Original_Object__c != null){
                            oldMedInfo.Original_Object__c = JSON.serialize(oldMedInfo);
                        }
                        oldMedInfo.put(field, newMedInfo.get(field));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    update medicalInfo;
    update violations;
}
```

I initially thought it might be `action='{!MVRController.applyInformation}'`, so I tried removing the `MVRController` and no longer got the error, but the code was not called on, either.

Anyone have any guesses as to why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: PLs format the code and then copy paste here. Also use `{}` to format code correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting `allowDML` to `true` according to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm)

> If this attribute is set to "true", you can include DML within the
>   component. The default is "false". Allowing DML can cause side-effects
>   that could be problematic for consumers using the component with
>   partial page updates. When allowing DML within a component, you should
>   include rerender attributes so the consumer can appropriately refresh
>   their page. In addition, you should detail, in the description of the
>   component, what data is manipulated by the DML so that consumers of
>   the component are aware of potential side-effects.

Comment: That was it. Thank you for the help!